# Unable to resolve the name vision.VideoFileReader Error in MATLAB

Tags: video

This is the code I am trying to execute on my HP Windows Laptop and I am ending up with the error msg  that it is "Unable to resolve the name vision.VideoFileReader"

Not getting what exactly is the issue. I have ensured the video file is selected from the right path but still not getting it. Kindly help

```
%% Setup the video reader and player
         vision.VideoFileReader('video1.mp4')
         videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('video1.mp4',...
               'VideoOutputDataType','double');
vidPlayer = vision.DeployableVideoPlayer;
```